# How can i make slickgrid keyboard navigation just like in excel?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slickgrid

I am using a slickgrid in angularjjs. I have set the "enableTextSelectionOnCells" and "enableCellNavigation" to true. Now when i navigate the grid using keyboard arrow keys, the scrolling is quite weird. To scroll using keyboard arrows, i first click a cell and then press down or up arrow, the current active cell gets changed upon pressing up or down key but it is not proper, meaning the next active when clicking down key is not the immediate next cell(downwards) - Just like this example https://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-spreadsheet.html

I want to excel like keyboard navigation in slickgrid, how can i achieve that.

Comment: working fine for me, on chrome for windows. what browser are you using? also, use the https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid repo now, MLeibman is unmaintained. There is also an 'emulatePagingWhenScrolling' option there to control how scrolling works.

Comment: this example http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example14-highlighting.html shows how scrolling behaves using keyboard arrow keys. It is not like excel

Comment: did you try option 'emulatePagingWhenScrolling=false'

Comment: so finally i noticed that this issue is only observed on chrome. I checked on firefox, keyboard navigation works perfectly. Waiting if anyone also faces the same issue

Comment: would be great if you could make a GIF of the problem using ShareX or other animated GIF capture software, like here: https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/issues/334  ... I really still have no idea what problem it is that you are experiencing

Answer (score 0):

After a week, I found that I was using a chrome extension called "smooth scroll" which used to override the behavior of slickgrid scroll. I removed the extension and scroll is working fine using keyboard arrows.